# Life after decapitation?

Tags: human-biology, zoology, entomology

I saw a video where an ant lost its head and was still walking for some time.

If this is possible for an arthropod, what keeps it from working with a vertebrate? (Humans, especially)

Comment: Cockroach bodies can survive without a head for up to two weeks. You cannot really physiologically compare an arthropod to a mammal, for many reasons.

Comment: Why? I just want to learn why this happens. I dont care if it is mammal, artopod, fish etc.

Comment: Arthropods. Segmented bodies, hemolymph, very simple nervous system. Mammals, unified body, blood, Central Nervous that is removed with head that controls many of the organ systems, endocrine system with hormones originating in the head and throat, organ failure from loss of blood....

Comment: So, you say that arthropod because they have different nervous system they can survive without head? Then why they have their brain??

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthropod

Comment: @Orphee You probably want to replace your title by `walking after decapitation` or `can a human walk after decapitation` or `motor activity after decapitation`. The concept of `life` is very different from the concept of  `walking`.

Comment: If someone walks, then he is alive (eg if u see a walking animal you will automaticaly understand that it is alive).